# How to change password on iOS Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It seems that when using the Stack Exchange app on iOS, I can't access my profile settings to change my password. Am I just over looking something, or is this the case with everyone else using the iOS app?

Comment: Should I delete this then? It didn't look like that question was answered either.

Comment: If the `close` button is available to you then I think you should use that to say that you recognize this to be a duplicate.